# Controller for Mailer in Ruby on Rails, Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailer

I followed a guide for setting up a mailer for ruby on rails (site of the guide: https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails ).

My preview looks like this: sample_email.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi <%= @user.username %></h1>
<p>
 Sie haben folgende Tags ausgewählt:
  <% @user.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
    <%= tag %> <br>
  <% end %>

  <br><br>
  <% @infosall.each do |info| %> #<-- Problem on this line
      <%= info.name %><br>
  <% end %><br>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

@user.username and @user.tag_list get rendered, but @infosall does not render. Where do I need to type in @infosall, so it gets rendered on the preview?

example_mailer_preview.rb:

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/example_mailer
class ExampleMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def sample_mail_preview
    ExampleMailer.sample_email(User.last)
  end
end
```

example_mailer.rb:

```
class ExampleMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: ""

  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')

  end
end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
    @tags = @user.tag_list
    @infosall = Array.new
    @tags.each do |tag|
      @infosall = @infosall + Info.tagged_with(tag)
    end

    @infosall.uniq!
    @infosall.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
  end

end
```

Edit: When I do this in example_mailer_preview.rb:

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/example_mailer
class ExampleMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def sample_mail_preview
    ExampleMailer.sample_email(User.last)

        @user = User.last
        @tags = @user.tag_list
        @infosall = Array.new
        @tags.each do |tag|
          @infosall = @infosall + Info.tagged_with(tag)
        end

        @infosall.uniq!
        @infosall.sort! { |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }
  end
end
```

I get a no method error: undefined method `find_first_mime_type' for # with this code:

```
def find_preferred_part(*formats)
  formats.each do |format|
    if part = @email.find_first_mime_type(format)
      return part
    end
  end
```

Where did I go wrong? Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailer is not related to controller. Also defining a `show` action for some model does not get it called when you render something with that model.

Think of mailer as of a controller, set all needed instance variable in its actions (`sample_email` in this case)

Comment: I added something in sample_email, but I get an error (see my edit), any advices?

Comment: @Metaphysiker you added code to your preview, not the mailer itself, preview should return a mail object

Answer (score 1):

`@infosall` should be an instance variable of ExampleMailer that gets passed along to the template, but you are not setting this variable in the mailer. You would need to set it in your `sample_email` method on your ExampleMailer in order for it to have any value or meaning in your template.

Comment: I added something in sample_email, but I get an error (see my edit), any advices?

Comment: You added it to `sample_email_preview`, not `sample_email`. As for the error you mentioned, it is in a method you aren't even calling from any of your posted code, so I'm not sure how it relates to the OP.